# Bayesian neural network in tensorflow-probability

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-probability

I am new to tensorflow and I am trying to set up a bayesian neural network with dense flipout-layers. My code looks as follows:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
import tensorflow as tf


def train_BNN(training_data, training_labels, test_data, test_labels, layers, epochs):

 bayesian_nn = Sequential()
 nbr_samples, dim = training_data.shape
 training_labels = training_labels.reshape((nbr_samples, 1))
 training_data = tf.convert_to_tensor(training_data, tf.float32)
 training_labels = tf.convert_to_tensor(training_labels, tf.float32)
 for i in range(0, len(layers)):
    bayesian_nn.add(tfp.layers.DenseFlipout(layers[i], activation='relu'))
 bayesian_nn.add(tfp.layers.DenseFlipout(1, activation='sigmoid'))

# Define loss function
 logits = bayesian_nn(training_data)
 neg_log_likelihood = tf.losses.sigmoid_cross_entropy(training_labels, logits=logits)
 kl = sum(bayesian_nn.losses)
 loss = neg_log_likelihood + kl
 # Define optimizer
 train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss)
 bayesian_nn.compile(train_op, loss=loss, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I get the following error when trying to compile the network:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test_script.py", line 34, in <module>
    dataset[0:training,], labels[0:training], dataset[training:,], labels[training:], layers, epochs
  File "/home/e/bayesian_nn.py", line 34, in train_BNN
    bayesian_nn.compile(train_op, loss=loss, metrics=['accuracy'])
  File "/home/e/.pyenv/versions/kmer_profiling/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/checkpointable/base.py", line 474, in _method_wrapper
    method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/e/.pyenv/versions/kmer_profiling/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 405, in compile
    loss = loss or {}
  File "/home/e/.pyenv/versions/kmer_profiling/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 671, in __bool__
    raise TypeError("Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. "
TypeError: Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. Use `if t is not None:` instead of `if t:` to test if a tensor is defined, and use TensorFlow ops such as tf.cond to execute subgraphs conditioned on the value of a tensor.
```

I don't know what's causing this error... please help :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `loss` you are passing into `model.compile` is a `tf.Tensor`, which is not allowed. Looking at [documentation](https://keras.io/losses/), it seems like you should be passing in the loss function (or string representation) directly, instead of instantiating it first, i.e. `loss=tf.losses.sigmoid_cross_entropy` (or a list of losses) instead of `loss=tf.losses.sigmoid_cross_entropy(training_labels, logits=logits)`